# I want to generate a image of UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone

In iPhone application I want to generate a image of `UIScrollView` whose content size is near about `600*41000`. If I use current graphic image context to capture the scroll view layer, then it only captures the visible part of the scroll view not the whole layer of that scroll view.

I am using the below code:

```
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(600, 4100));
    [scrollView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();



    UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(00, 100, 710, 4100)];
    img.image = viewImage;
    [anotherScrollView addSubview:img];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to generate image not from `UIScrollView` but from its content view. When you add some views to `UIScrollView` with something like `addSubview:` they become scroll's content ones. Of course, `UIScrollView` can have more than one content view (just as any `UIView` can have more than one subview) and this case it will be more difficult to render its layer. But in case of only one subview (content view) you can use something like (`contentView` here is just some view, added to `UIScrollView` before):

`[contentView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];`

or:

`[[[[scrollView subviews] lastObject] layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];`

When you want to use more than one view, it will be easier (I think) to add one more "root" view and add others as that view's subviews: so you can also use the code above.

Comment: Ok. My code line differs from yours. Replace yours with mine and try.

Comment: its sending an error message that member'contentView' is something not a structure or union.